# Add firewall rules on GCE for an application deployed on GAE

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-compute-engine, firewall

My post has been considered as a duplicate, but this is not...
This question [How to access mongodb on GCE with GAE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46347428/how-to-access-mongodb-on-gce-with-gae) does not answer to how can I edit firewall rules of GCE for an GAE application. It mentioned only about how can how to get te URI to set on an app running on GAE.

This is not my issue. I'd like to make a firewall rule for a deployed GAE application, I already have the external IP of my GCE set on my GAE app.

For example : on my GAE server I can make a dig to get the local server IP (for example : 35.187.8.45), so I can add it to my GCE firewall rules, then in my GAE shell I can make a "python main.py" and access to my mongodb on GCE.
But when I run a "gcloud app deploy", it does not run on the same server anymore. So I have to know on which one to edit a new firewall rules and allow the deployed application.

Hope to be clearer this time...

Comment: Is your app running on GAE Standard or Flexible?

Comment: Hello LundinCast. I run on standard GAE

Comment: Too late on this but you could also use [VPC Conector](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python3/connecting-vpc) with App Engine Standard and connect through internal IP and remove all external access on your GCE instance.

Answer (score 1):

Well, I finally find a way to achieve what I wanted.

The way to go is to create a GAE flexible, thus, I can find under **Instances** my diffent VM which have an IP and add them to my GCE (where is my MongoDB) firewall rules.

What I understand of it, but maybe I'm wrong, is in flexible environement, application of GAE is deployed in several VM, running on compute engine, which is not the case for standard environement.

So, for people needs same, and doesn't want to expose their app to whole internet (0.0.0.0/0), go to a flexible environement